# Executing a Windows process from Windows 8 app using Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I am working on a Windows 8 app where i want to execute a process with its parameters. Say "shutdown.exe"

I am working on the app in Javascript and HTML5. As far as i have researched it is not possible to do the same due to sandboxing (which i am not sure).

So is there a way to invoke a command process within a Windows 8 App ?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The closest thing is protocol activation, whereby an app can launch another via a URL. You can register an app to respond to any URI you want, but if someone else does the same, then your app won't run by default, and the user will be prompted to select which app they want to use to respond to the launch request.

You can check out how this works via the [Application launching sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec) and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx).